# Processing Beat Detecting

Tags: audio, processing

I am using processing and the minim library and trying to create a 3D real-time visualisation for live audio input.

i have boxes drawn and is responding to the kick, snare , and hi hats of the audio input.  I am looking to make these boxes rotate also responding to the kick ect.  how could i make these boxes rotate?

```java
if ( beat.isKick() ) kickSize = 200;
if ( beat.isSnare() ) snareSize = 250;
if ( beat.isHat() ) hatSize = 200;
translate ( width/4, height/4);
box(kickSize);
translate( - width/4, - height/4);

translate ( width/2, height/3);
sphere(snareSize);
translate( - width/2, - height/3);

translate ( 3*width/4, height/4);
box(hatSize);
translate( - 3*width/4, - height/4);


kickSize = constrain(kickSize * 0.95, 1, 32);
snareSize = constrain(snareSize * 0.95, 1, 32);
hatSize = constrain(hatSize * 0.95, 1, 32);
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You can use the `rotate()` function to rotate shapes. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: to get the shape to rotate each time the 'kick' is detected

Comment: translate ( width/4, height/4);
    box(kickSize);
rotate(kickSize);
    translate( - width/4, - height/4);

this seems to rotate everything. i would like to rotate each box separately

Answer (score 0):

Use `pushMatrix();popMatrix();` calls to isolate coordinate systems for each object:

```
pushMatrix();
translate ( width/4, height/4);
box(kickSize);
popMatrix();

pushMatrix();
translate ( width/2, height/3);
sphere(snareSize);
popMatrix();

pushMatrix();
translate ( 3*width/4, height/4);
box(hatSize);
popMatrix();
```

Have a look at the [2D transformations Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) for more details.
The same principle applies to 3D